# How to get scrollbars showing when when using an accordian in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
function pageLoad() {

    $('#accordion h3').click(function() {
        $(this).next().toggle();
        return false;
    }).next().hide();

<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">Section A</a></h3>
    <div id="a">
        <Ctrl:A id="a" runat="server"></Ctrl:A>
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#">Section B</a></h3>
    <div id="b">
         <Ctrl:B id="b" runat="server"></Ctrl:B>
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#">Section c</a></h3>
    <div id="c">
         <Ctrl:C id="c" runat="server"></Ctrl:C>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem I am having is when say Setion A dn Section B are expanded, no scroll bars are showing in the broweser window and some fields are below the page and I have to tab to get to them and dont get a browser scrollbar.How can I get the scrollbar when the expansion is more than the height of the window?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have overflow:hidden set on your page? The page should have a scrollbar when you expand past its boundaries unless you've told it not to. Are you doing any sort of fixed or absolute positioning?

Also, is this a big problem given that by your code, you should never have two sections open at once?

Comment: I have 2 sections open when there are validation error messages on 2 sections....I dont have any overflow settings on the page set at all. All I want to do is if 2 sections are open, I want the scrollbar to show..I can get the height of the opened divs using jQuery and can check if they are greater than window.height but I dont know what to do after that and how to show the scrollbars.

Comment: What about positioning? browsers by default should just... show scrollbars if the pages content gets too large. Do you have a demo page of this sitting somewhere that I can see?